# ASP.NET MVC AJAX call Application/Controller/Action?

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, routes

An Ajax call works fine in Visual Studio 2019 debug but when deployed Fiddler shows that the calls to controller calls follow 'Application/Controller/Action' routing but the Ajax call to the controller doesn't add the web app name and so the controller action isn't found.

Is there a good article/tutorial fro using Route Debugger for remote websites/services?

This is what the routing file contains:

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

[IMAGE Fiddler Ajax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B31Gy.jpg)

Ajax call configuration:

```
var strURL = "/Examples/GetTaskData";
    var thisresult;

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",

        data: JSON.stringify
            ({
                'mapPointsString': mapPointsString


            }),


        url: strURL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        async: false,

        success: function (result) {
            thisresult = result;


        },
        failure: function (response) {

            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            var alerttext = xhr.status + xhr.responseText + thrownError;
            alert(alerttext);
            alert(xhr.status); alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
```

Controller/Action:

```
 [HttpPost]       
         [Route("/Examples/GetTaskData/")]
         [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public ActionResult GetTaskData(string mapPointsString)
        {
CODE
}
```

Thanks for your help 
Stew

Comment: Could you also show the code for the ajax call?

Comment: Most import was to mention in your question how ajax request is prepared

Comment: added the ajax call and index detail as suggested. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all is good. Its the ActionLink on the Navbar that isn't routing correctly.

I will have a look at this and create a new StakeOverflow question if needed.

This question can be closed.